# Issue with errors in Unity on launch

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am having an issue in Unity where every time I launch the editor it asks me to enter in safe mode because there are a lot of errors and when I press ignore it launches and I can see in the console a lot of errors with the UI and I found out that I cant create UI elements directly in the hierarchy. I tried to update from 2020.3.13f1 to 2020.3.14f1 and for the first launch everything was fine, with no errors, and I could create UI elements but then when I restarted to make sure everything was actually fine, all the errors popped up again and I cant create UI. Why does this happen and does anyone have a fix because I can't find it anywhere online.

Comment: Safe mode is not intended to be used to work on your game, it's created [solely for resolving script compilation errors](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/Manual/SafeMode.html). You would need to fix your script errors before you can edit your project.

Comment: I don't think its a script compilation error because the errors give out the namespace UnityEngine.UI doesn't exist, than it loads for 5-10 min and all the errors are gone.

Comment: Sounds like something went awry with your initial installation of Unity. Did you just recently install Unity and then saw this issue? You may want to consider uninstalling Unity completely and reinstalling it. This may be quite a nightmare to troubleshoot otherwise.

Comment: Denis, have you looked in Editor.log? (you share it)? In that log you may find more details about what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to enter Safe Mode. Enter the editable project. There go to Assets-Reimport All.

It did it to me too, it's probably a Unity bug, this method fixes it. Practically it reimports the whole project by itself, avoiding that the bug gives you problems (such as those like UnityEngine.UI does not exist or Monobehavior does not exist, etc.)

Obviously you will not lose any assets and everything will be fine as before receiving the errors.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I even did some restarts to make sure and I got no errors anywhere and the UI tab in the hierarchty is always there.

Answer (score 0):

Have this issue with any template 2020+ versions
Always shows 2 empty errors on console at first run ,even on an empty project

Will try to install 2019 and hopefully work again

Answer (score 0):

in my case some side app ran caused some error in the installation of Unity.
Nothing amid aboves helped.

Thus I decided to fully reinstall it from scratch to default one.
Now it worksok. But before that . To wipe out the Unity thorowly you need in:

1. uninstalling Unity and UnityHub in windows' settings
2. remove all related/remained folders in "*C:\Program Files*"
3. remove  related/remained folders in "*C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local* "
4. in Register Editor go to clean unity like folders in "*Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE*"
5. optionally, remove sample projects in "*C:\Users\myname*"

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed unity hub on my linux laptop and installed the unity editor but when i created a new project, i was given two compilation errors that had no name or details.

Answer (score -3):

You're very likely simply **opening the wrong folder**, it's a common mistake

---

Or, you have possibly **moved around the folders that you cannot move**

---

Also - it's a nuisance but it's best to install the "hub"

Comment: How can you open `the wrong folder`? Unity only lets you open a project if you actually open a project ^^

Comment: cheers @derHugo - you know I don't remember the precise details (and indeed it may have changed) but this used to be a "thing" at one point w/ Unity ..  it was something to do with, if you had copied a folder or such